# SQL Delete items not in list

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

**Summary**

If I want to remove some items from a database using SQL, I would have something like:

```
DELETE FROM ScannedFiles 
WHERE Name NOT IN (`Picture1.bmp`, `Picture2.bmp`, `Picture3.bmp`}
```

But how to remove a variable list of about 250 items?

```
IEnumerable<string> existingFileNames = ...

using (var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    dbCommand.CommandText = ...

    foreach (string fileName in existingFileNames)
    {
        ... change commandText, and / or add parameters
    }

    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Is there a smarter way with a different SQL statement?

**For those who want background information**

I want to write a program which helps me to find duplicate files and large files, so I can decide whether I can remove them.

Scanning all hard disks, the online drives and the NAS takes quite a while. Therefore I thought it would be a nice exercise for me to put the data in a database.

As I am talking about thousands of files, adding all date to the database must be efficient. Querying data may be less efficient. So for bulk updating the database I use SQL, for inspecting and finding duplicate I use Entity Framework.

All works fine, I can scan all drives, and fetch scanned files and directories.

Because a full scan takes hours, I want to be able to do a rescan without having to scan all directories again. I only want to scan directories of which I suspect that files or subdirectories might be added / removed / changed.

During the rescan, whenever I find a file or directory that is in the database, but does not exist anymore, I want to remove it from the database.

```
class ScannedFile
{
    public Id {get; set;}             // primary key
    public DirectoryId {get; set;}    // foreign key to the directories table

    public string Name {get; set;}    // name without DirectoryName
    public long Size {get; set;}
    public DateTime FileDate {get; set;}
}
```

I don't save the full file name, because this way I can easily find duplicates of `MyPicture.bmp` in different directories.

The combination of `[DirectoryId, Name]` has a unique constraint: all files in one directory have a unique filename.

So, during my rescan, if have a Directory, with some files, and I need to remove the files in the database that do not exist anymore.

If I would have only a few fileNames, I would have something like:

```
DELETE FROM ScannedFiles 
WHERE Name NOT IN (`Picture1.bmp`, `Picture2.bmp`, `Picture3.bmp`}
```

But now I have a large sequence of fileNames of variable length

```
IEnunumerable<string> existingFileNames = ...

using (var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    dbCommand.CommandText = ...
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(...);
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

So is there any SQL method, other than `NOT IN (..., ..., ...)` to solve this?

I'm using the newest SQLite nuget package "SQLite by SQLite development team 3.13.0", but I am willing to change to a different SQLite version.

Comment: How about putting the name of the files in a temporary table and use '`DELETE FROM ScannedFiles SF WHERE Name not in (SELECT Name FROM myTempTable)` ?

Comment: If you were using SQL Server i would say use a Table Valued Parameter. Unfortunately SQLite doesn't have that, perhaps use a temporary table instead?

Comment: Adding variable number of parameters with string values like your example wouldnt be reliable. It may look working in test situations but may hit the sql command parameter limit (max around 2100 params as I remember) and/or sql command size limit (256mb according to the defaults). Dont do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 250 is the worst case, I would keep it simple and go ahead with a `not in (...)` clause (with bound parameters, not literal values).

The maximum number of bound parameters is 999 for SQLite versions before 3.32.0
and 32766 after that.

In my experience SQLite handles surprisingly well a few hundred bound parameters,
e.g. queries like `select ... where some_indexed_column in (?, ?, ...)` with 800 parameters in a 300K lines table (with [sqlite-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net/) on an Android device)